# How to load video list in webview from google search in android

Tags: android, webview, google-search

I am developing video downloader app. where i want to show video list in webview for the search result of user. I have EditTextBox where the user enters search item like Funny video, and then press button, and it should load video list in webview. but currently, i can only show the search result as ALL, not Video.
please see attachment.
I am using this query for Google search

```
 webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q="+query_string);
```

[image: Search result i get]

[image: Search result I NEED]

Comment: whats the problem you are facing? can you share your code?

Comment: you have to use google API to fetch details

Comment: try here https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a few dummy Google searches to find out a plausible solution for this. In these searches, I tried to figure out the URL pattern between 'All' search results and 'Video' results. Suppose our search query is "hello"

What I found is that for 'All' results page, the simplest URL is this :-

> https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello

While, for the same query, the simplest URL for 'Video' results is this :-

> https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello&source=lnms&tbm=vid

Therefore, in your `Webview` query, you could simply replace your existing query with the following in order to show your 'Video' results :-

```
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello"+query_string+"&source=lnms&tbm=vid");
```

Though, please note the following things :-

1. I tested these URLs on Google Chrome, and I do not know if they'd work on browsers such as Safari.
2. The URLs mentioned above are the simplest representations. The actual URL that are displayed in my browser have more fields.

Comment: Yes, That is working fine in Google Chrome, but i will must check in safari etc,

Comment: Yes, absolutely!